# Highcharts and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, sql, highcharts

I was trying to pull data from DB to Highcharts polar chart, and when I try to load it on browser I get this error in the browser's inspector tools:

`SyntaxError: missing } after property list on Line 78`

This is the code I've used.

EDIT: IVE PUT DIFFERENT CODE FIRST TIME

```
    <?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","uwguru");
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Highcharts Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        ${demo.css}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $('#container').highcharts({

                chart: {
                    polar: true,
                    type: 'line'
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'Muscle Summary',
                    x: -80
                },

                pane: {
                    size: '80%'
                },

                xAxis: {
                    categories: [
                        <?php
                        $sql="SELECT * FROM exercises";
                        $result= mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
                        while ($registros = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                        {
                        ?>
                            <?php echo $registros['main_muscle']?>,

                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    ],
                    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
                    lineWidth: 0
                },

                yAxis: {
                    gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
                    lineWidth: 0,
                    min: 0
                },

                tooltip: {
                    shared: true,
                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>${point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
                },

                legend: {
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    y: 70,
                    layout: 'vertical'
                },

                series: [{
                    name: 'Test',
                    data: [
                        <?php
                        $sql="SELECT * FROM exercises";
                        $result= mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
                        while ($registros = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                        {
                        ?>
                        <?php echo $registros['muscle_string']?>,

                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>

                    ]
                    pointPlacement: 'on'}],


            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="js/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

RENDERED SOURCE CODE

```
<

!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Highcharts Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        ${demo.css}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $('#container').highcharts({

                chart: {
                    polar: true,
                    type: 'line'
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'Muscle Summary',
                    x: -80
                },

                pane: {
                    size: '80%'
                },

                xAxis: {
                    categories: [
                        ["1","14","13","1","14","1","7","9","16"]
                                            ],
                    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
                    lineWidth: 0
                },

                yAxis: {
                    gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
                    lineWidth: 0,
                    min: 0
                },

                tooltip: {
                    shared: true,
                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>${point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
                },

                legend: {
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    y: 70,
                    layout: 'vertical'
                },

                series: [{
                    name: 'Test',
                    data: [
                        ["6","745","7547","4","5","1","2","634234","325235"]

                    ]
                    pointPlacement: 'on'}


            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="js/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: pointPlacement: 'on'}],

Comment: As you can see you are missing the closing square bracket on the `series:[]` object. Your `series.data` values are also all strings ("6", "745", etc). Highcharts requires data values to be numeric not strings. Look at doing json encoding of numeric values.

Comment: @wegeld they are not strings anymore

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of your `while` loop.

Also, consider building your array and outputting it to JSON using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Note that you will still have to parse the JSON on the JavaScript side. If you are going to mix javascript and PHP, it's usually better practice output the JS data separately (like as a variable above the JS logic) and then parse it where you need it. It makes maintaining the code in the future a lot easier.

```
<?php
    // put this in above the `$('#container').highcharts({` line 
    //and you can access it as a proper JS variable as you need to.
    $sql="SELECT * FROM exercises";
    $result= mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
    $output = [];    
    while ($registros = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $output[] = $registros['muscle_string'];
    }
    echo "var muscleString = JSON.parse('".json_encode($output)."');";
?>
```

That said, the error you are getting is that you probably need this:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Test',
    data: [
        ["6","745","7547","4","5","1","2","634234","325235"]
    ]
    pointPlacement: 'on'}
```

To ultimately look like this:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Test',
    data: [
        ["6","745","7547","4","5","1","2","634234","325235"]
    ], // <-- add comma here
    pointPlacement: 'on'
}] // <-- close your array with a closing square bracket
```

Comment: that code doesnt help :/

Comment: I updated the answer. If you give that a try and it doesn't work, please post the rendered HTML source code so the community can better assist you. Right now we are trying to assist with a syntax error that we cannot see. It is very likely that something in your while loop is not rendering valid JS code. Interpreters rarely report errors on the correct line number when closing brackets are the problem.

Comment: I've added code, thank you for helping me with this

Comment: Hopefully my edits will help you.

Comment: SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'var'

Comment: now im getting no render on frontside, and inspector shows no errors

Comment: A plain white screen usually means a PHP error and `display_errors` is off or `log_errors` is set to off.